# Creating a blank CSV file Snowflake Staging area

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was working on creating the staging area in Snowflake and creating CSV files inside it. I am stuck up with an issue, hope someone here is experienced enough to help me in the case.

I have created a job in unix to create a CSV file in a staging area from a table added with where conditions to filter the data. But, when at times if there are no rows as output as the result of the select statement from the table, the CSV file is not at all created in the staging area. Is there any way in such cases a CSV file is created with the name of the columns alone with no value rows?

Thanks in advance.
Rahul

Comment: Why would you want an empty file created in your staging area? If a unix job is creating your files, isn't this a unix question rather than a Snowflake question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the header=true option in your COPY INTO?